# How to insert HTML page (HTML page with button,combo etc) or Infopath Form (.XSN file) as inline content of email body in MS Outlook

Tags: outlook, ms-office

I have requirement to add interactive HTML form as inline content of email body in MS Outlook. For example if I open any jpg in paint and copy paste it to email body area then it will be displayed as inline content of email body. In similar way I need HTML page to be displayed in email body area and user should be able to interact with that. Similar functionality is there in InfoPath which opens Outlook UI to send InfoPath form through email so you can refer that.

I want to know whether such thing is possible or not. If possible then I need to do it programmatically but first I need to check whether it is possible  manually or not.

If requirement is not clear then let me know so I will try to give you more detail.

Comment: It is ok if I can embed InfoPath .xsn (form) into outlook. There is option in InfoPath to send email with embedded .xsn file but I do not want it. I need to embed html or .xsn in MS Outlook email body.

Comment: I need to it programmatically by developing add-in for Outlook. Before that first I want to confirm whether it is possible manually or not. If possible manually then I will post another thread to have information about how to do it programatically